# How to change setting of Gmail to view HTML emails?

Tags: gmail, html

This may sound like a dumb question, but I am having trouble with viewing a link (not in the form of a URL but some text that redirects you to a page once clicked) in one of the emails I have received.

I have done some Google search but it did not yield anything useful - the mostly focus on how to change the UI from using AJAX to plain HTML.

One suggestion I had was change the setting of the account so that the emails that I open are viewed as HTML rather than plain text, but frankly I was not able to find that option in my account settings. I am hoping anyone could either direct me to change the account setting to view the email as a HTML and not a plain text, or provide other possibilities as to why the link cannot be clicked. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -2):

The direct link to basic HTML view is: https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html&zy=h

From the Gmail help page.

** update: if you sign out (of standard view) then sign back in, a link appears in the lower right while your inbox loading screen is up. Not as convenient as having the link permanently available below your inbox, I agree -- but better than using that awkward direct link perhaps.

Addition to above: Once you are signed into basic gmail using above info, click on the "basic view" option at the top right on your Inbox page. This will convert you to basic permanently, or until you want to change back to standard.